# nginx Restrict or Redirect requests to go through index.php in the root

Tags: nginx, slim, nginx-location, nginx-config

My project requirement is to launch an angular(v6)/ionic(v4) app(index.html) from Slim framework (index.php).
The root folder structure is attached in the image below:
[image]

'www' is the root directory where the Slim index.php lies. Inside 'www' is the app folder where the angular build files(index.php) are added. 
The requirement is that all the requests should go through Slim index.php in the root folder and based on some session logic we have to route or launch the angular app (index.html).

Right now, 'https://domain/' goes through index.php. But,
'https://domain/app/' directly launches the angular app (index.html).

How can I configure nginx so that all requests are to be handled in the root directory by Slim index.php ?

```
server {
    server_name <domain>;

    root /var/www/<some name>/public/www/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/<some name>.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/<some name>.log;

    sendfile off;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 36000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Mybe you can restrict acces to your `app` folder or redirect all `https://domain/app/` requests to `https://domain` i can give you the code if this will solve your problem

Comment: Hi @ABDELLATIFLAKEHAL, It would be helpful if you could share the code. My requirement is to restrict access to the app folder and redirect to root. I have tried redirect and rewrite with no success but that can be because of my inexpertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can restrict access to your `app` directory like so

```
location /app {
    deny all;
    return 404; #show not found instead of 403
}
```

Or you can override the 403 handling by sending a redirect to `https://example.com/`

```
location /app{
     deny all;
     error_page 403 https:/domain.com/;  #redirect to your main directory
 }
```